# Add new stream to Gstreamer recording

Tags: streaming, recording, audio-recording, audio-streaming, gstreamer

I currently have a set of streams that I record using GStreamer and an SDP with a similar command as follows

`gst-launch-1.0 --eos-on-shutdown filesrc location=test.sdp ! sdpdemux timeout=0 name=demux webmmux name=mux ! filesink location=test.webm demux. ! queue ! rtpopusdepay ! opusparse  ! mux.`

This is working fine for multiple streams that are declared in the SDP. However, there are times when a stream may come in late so they are not part of the original SDP at record time. Is there a way to update the recording process so that it can add the new stream to its current recording in progress?

open to other suggestions too.

Answer (score 0):

You can,  but only if you dont use the gst-launch cli which is recommendedto user only for debugging purposes. Gstreamer is designed to be used in code (c/c++ and bindings in c#, python,  rust, java...). There you can access the different elements on runtime. U can either restart the pipe with the updated sdp or add the specific stream to the mix without restarting but not through sdp.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).